# Analysis Services – Errors when trying to remove a User who is a Server Admin

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssas-2012

Getting following error when trying to remove a user from SSAS Server Administrator.

*The following system error occurred:  No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices)*

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that some user or group who is currently a server admin has been deleted in Active Directory. Basically when it scripts out the change to the server admin members it lists all the members. When it tries to apply the members it does an Active Directory lookup and if that lookup fails it throws that error.

If the Server Admins list has any users which only show an identifier that looks like a GUID that may be your culprit. Otherwise research which users don't exist and remove those users as server admins while you remove the other user you are trying to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer cmdlet. 
You would need the AzureRM.AnalysisServices in Powershell.

Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -Name "aasserver" -ResourceGroupName "aasgroup" -Administrator "abc@xyz.com, def@xyz.com"